# OptaPlanner Multiple Terminations on Local Search

Tags: optaplanner

Like the title says, I have the following configuration:

```xml
<localSearch>
    <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
    <termination>
        <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
        <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>5</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
        <secondsSpentLimit>10</secondsSpentLimit>
    </termination>
</localSearch>
```

With this configuration, the local search should stop after 10 seconds. But it does not. I will have to wait until `unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit` is triggered.

So how can I make the local search stop if the solution cannot be easily improved OR when its runtime exceeds a given duration?

Comment: Code wise, everything looks ok: see `OrCompositionTermination.isPhaseTerminated()` line 60.

Comment: If this is true, this is a bug. A regression even, because I know this worked at some point. But I doubt it. Copy paste AndCompositeTerminationTest to create a OrCompositeTerminationTest to prove me wrong :)

Comment: I totally forgot to mention that I am using OptaPlanner 7.22.0.Final, sorry.

Comment: I'll try to do as you say !

Comment: I don't recall any fixes for this since 7.22. I'd love to see your DEBUG log for category org.optaplanner to prove this with the "Phase ended" log message's spent time value. And a reproducing unit test of course :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a OrCompositeTerminationTest, as mentioned by Geoffrey : everything is working as it should in OptaPlanner.

I found why my case was not working : here, OptaPlanner is configured with an xml file. But I was not aware that a bit of our code was messing with the termination conditions once the solver was built.

I am terribly sorry to have made you loose your time on something that dumb !

Answer (score 1):

The OrCompositionTermination works for me both with current master branch and 7.22.0.Final tag. Could you please try turning on logging as Geoffrey suggested?